# sklearn.datasets.make_s_curve output meaning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, output

the `sklearn.datasets` has a function called `make_s_curve` that returns a dataset that represent a 3D S shape looks like this: [image: 3D S shape]

The function returns the dataset with is of shape [num_samples, 3]. It also returns a second output which is of shape [num_samples] and explained that it is

> the univariate position of the sample according to the main dimension
>   of the points in the manifold.

I don't understand what this mean, is this some particular ordering of the points in the dataset ?

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

> the univariate position

This means that the postion will not change

> according to the main dimension of the points

And the order of the position is based on the main dimension.

> in the manifold

and [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) is a topological space.

The idea behind that is that you can compare the plot, and the points always have the same order in respect to their dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are saying, do you mean that the second output is some numeric value that we can used to order the points ? (sorting the second output would create an ordred sequence of points by one of the 3 dimension) ?

Comment: The `make_s_curve` return `X`, and `t`. Does it mean `X` is the `training values` and `t` is the `target`?

Comment: what is x and t for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have been asking the same question for the `make_swiss_roll` method, which has the same signature as `make_s_curve`, and whose docs contain the exact same description of the second term. Following the references in the `make_swiss_roll` docs I have found the answer:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_swiss_roll.html#sklearn.datasets.make_swiss_roll

The docs for the `make_swiss_roll` reference the following textbook for the underlying algorithm:

[https://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~marslast/Code/Ch6/lle.py](https://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/%7Emarslast/Code/Ch6/lle.py)

which contains the following snippet of code, where we can see how this second term is defined:

```
def swissroll():
    # Make the swiss roll dataset
    N = 1000
    noise = 0.05

    t = 3*np.pi/2 * (1 + 2*np.random.rand(1,N))
    h = 21 * np.random.rand(1,N)
    data = np.concatenate((t*np.cos(t),h,t*np.sin(t))) + noise*np.random.randn(3,N) 
    return np.transpose(data), np.squeeze(t)
```

If we think of the swiss roll as a rectangle with width parameterised by `t` and height parameterised by `h`, then the `swissroll` function returns the array of `t`-values as well as the array of points of the form `(t*np.cos(t),h,t*np.sin(t))`. The S-curve will have its own corresponding equation, where the `x` and `z` terms are transformed in a different way (the exact algorithm isn't referenced in the docs, but you could find it in the source code).

The mysterious "univariate position of the sample" is simply the array of input `t`-values that parameterise one dimension of the rectangle ("univariate" means "of a single variable").

To see why it is useful to return the array of input `t`-values, consider the image contained in your question: notice how the colours of the points change -- the colour is determined by the point's corresponding `t`-value (rather than the `x,y,z` coordinates of the point) i.e. high `t`-values are purple, low `t`-values are yellow.